# Repetir códigos com laço de repetição while

Tags: python, while

Não estou conseguindo executar um laço `while` dentro de outro `while`.

Usei o código abaixo, que faz tudo certo, mas na hora que digito 1 ele só repete a pergunta "Deseja repetir? digite 1 para sim e 2 para não:", e eu quero que repita o programa todo mas ele só repete a ultima frase.

```
resp = int(1)

n1 = -1

n2 = -1

while resp == 1:

    while n1 > 10 or n1 < 0:
        n1 = float(input("Qual valor da sua primeira nota?: "))
        if n1 > 10 or n1 < 0:
            print('Nota invalida.')
    while n2 > 10 or n2 < 0:
        n2 = float(input("Qual valor da sua segunda nota?: "))
        if n2 > 10 or n2 < 0:
            print('Nota invalida.')
        media = (n1 + n2) / 2
        print('A sua média foi de {}'.format(media))
    resp = int(input('Deseja repetir? digite 1 para sim e 2 para não: '))
```

Comment: Isso acontece porque o `n1` e `n2` continuam com o valor digitado, reinicialize as duas variáveis depois da pergunta _"Deseja repetir?"_

Answer (score 0):

Antes quando o programa acabava se o usuário quisesse executá-lo de novo não conseguia, porque não entrava nos loops `while n1 > 10 or n1 < 0` e `while n1 > 10 or n1 < 0`, devido ao fato da condição nos loops ser falsa, isso porque no fim do programa as variáveis `n1` e `n2` estariam com um valor abaixo de 10 e acima de 0, há 2 maneiras para corrigir isso:

1 - Mantendo a estrutura do seu código (resetando as variáveis quando o programa é executado novamente)

```
resp = int(1)
n1 = -1
n2 = -1

while resp == 1:

    if resp == 2:
        n1 = -1
        n2 = -1

    while n1 > 10 or n1 < 0:
        n1 = float(input("Qual valor da sua primeira nota?: "))
        if n1 > 10 or n1 < 0:
            print('Nota invalida.')

    while n2 > 10 or n2 < 0:
        n2 = float(input("Qual valor da sua segunda nota?: "))
        if n2 > 10 or n2 < 0:
            print('Nota invalida.')

    media = (n1 + n2) / 2
    print('A sua média foi de {}'.format(media))
    resp = int(input('Deseja repetir? digite 1 para sim e 2 para não: '))
```

2 - Forma pythônica, visualmente mais bonito/agradável e fácil de compreender:

```
resp = 1

while resp == 1:

    while True:
        n1 = float(input("Qual valor da sua primeira nota?: "))
        if n1 > 10 or n1 < 0:
            print('Nota invalida.')
        else:
            break

    while True:
        n2 = float(input("Qual valor da sua segunda nota?: "))
        if n2 > 10 or n2 < 0:
            print('Nota invalida.')
        else:
            break

    media = n1 + n2 / 2
    print(f'A sua média foi de {media}')
    # Se estiver usando o python 3.6 ou inferior utilize: print('A sua média foi de {}'.format(media))
    resp = int(input('Deseja repetir? digite 1 para sim e 2 para não: '))
```